# EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase Not Resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, odp.net

I've been working through deploying an ASP.NET MVC website to IIS 7.5, and I'm experiencing the following error message:

```
[ArgumentException: The type 'EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase, EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.]
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.AssemblyQualifiedTypeNameConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +189
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DbProviderMapping.get_DatabaseType() +48
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDatabaseData(ConnectionStringSettings connectionString, DatabaseSettings databaseSettings) +38
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.<get_Databases>d__0.MoveNext() +272
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +460
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.<DoGetRegistrations>d__10.MoveNext() +137
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetRegistrations(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +161
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.<GetRegistrations>b__0(ITypeRegistrationsProvider p, IConfigurationSource cs) +8
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.GetRegistrationsInternal(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, Func`3 registrationAccessor) +74
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.GetRegistrations(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +80
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.CompositeTypeRegistrationsProviderLocator.<GetRegistrations>b__0(ITypeRegistrationsProvider l, IConfigurationSource cs) +8
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetRegistrationsInternal>b__4(ITypeRegistrationsProvider l) +16
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +234
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator.RegisterAllCore(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider) +127
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ChangeTrackingContainerConfigurator.RegisterAll(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider) +23
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(ITypeRegistrationsProvider locator, IContainerConfigurator configurator, IConfigurationSource configSource) +19
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(IContainerConfigurator configurator, IConfigurationSource configSource) +117
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +59
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.SetCurrentContainerIfNotSet() +80
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.get_Current() +5
   InventoryScanner.DataAccess.RepositoryBase..ctor() in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.DataAccess\RepositoryBase.cs:56
   InventoryScanner.DataAccess.ScannerRepository..ctor() in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.DataAccess\ScannerRepository.cs:18
   InventoryScanner.Common.Logger.LogHelper..ctor() in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.Common.Logger\LogHelper.cs:26
   InventoryScanner.Web.Filters.LogExceptionFilterAttribute..ctor() in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.Web.Filters\Filters.cs:19
   InventoryScanner.Web.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.Web\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:45
   InventoryScanner.Web.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\michaelj\Desktop\warehouse server\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner\InventoryScanner.Web\Global.asax.cs:21

[HttpException (0x80004005): The type 'EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase, EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): The type 'EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase, EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

My research has indicated that the DI aspect of EntLib isn't properly resolving EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.dll despite the fact that it is in the website bin directory.

I've Googled and Binged the ArgumentException line and EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase but did not see anything that that brought me closer than what I've already stated.

I did not write this application, nor do I have any experience or understanding of EntLib. I asked the person who did write the application last week and still haven't heard from him, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the setup. Unfortunately, the details were never discovered. We redeployed it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience with you, while running my site with visual studio, 
I got ArgumentException message while running my site with visual studio.

In my case, I have it from onLoad method in my WebBase implementation.

So, I add a try catch statement on my code in which the problem occurred.
Actually, Skipping it even if some exception occurred.

```
try
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
catch (ArgumentException e1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e1.StackTrace);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e1.StackTrace);
}
```

Then tell the compiler ignore this exception by unckecking the item 'stop when this exception occurred'. That's all.

Comment: You should post your own question with more details about your specific situation and answer it yourself. This has no relevance to my issue and is inappropriate as an answer to it.